# safari mobile got a negative http error status on ajax

Tags: ajax, mobile-safari, http-status-codes

A safari error quite strange -which does not occur on firefox nor chrome nor... iexplore- : negative code status on very specific ajax requests.

There is absolutely no log on apache and the exact same requests works perfectly on other browsers.
Some have reported from the latest safari on iPhones, I reproduced the issue on my computer using version 5.1.7

[image: strange status on safari]

The code making the request is the same on all browsers, using latest jQuery.

Any idea, even silly, is welcome x_x

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12176795/jquery-ajax-does-not-work-in-safari-when-it-takes-seconds-to-get-returned-dat

Comment: Thanks, I did not find it in my researches but it seems to not be the same problem: my call is already asynchronous and the issue started 2 days ago, not one year ago.